# Show relation for integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f \in C^{1}([a,b];\mathbb{R})$ and $|f'(x)-f'(y)| \le L |x-y|$ 
then we have $|\int_a^b f(x) dx -f(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a)| \le L\frac{(b-a)^3}{4}$.

I have troubles to show this inequality. the problem is that i need to have a difference of derivatives of the function in order to use the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: $f(\frac{b-a}{2})$ should be $f(\frac{a+b}{2})$.

Comment: would this change something? (it is very likely that the excercise is somehow wrong)

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $[a,b]$. In general, $\frac{b-a}{2}$ is even not in $[a,b]$.

Comment: you're right. the excercise is only meaningful is we have $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Do you have any idea how to go on?

Comment: It seems that the bound is also inaccurate. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. By [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for every $x\in[a,c]$(resp. $[c,b]$), there exists $t\in[x,c]$(resp. $[c,x]$), such that 
$$f(x)-f(c)=f'(t)(x-c).$$
It follows that
$$|f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)|=|(f'(t)-f'(c))(x-c)|\le L|(t-c)(x-c)|\le L(x-c)^2.$$
Integrating the inequality above over $[a,b]$, it follows that
$$\big|\int_a^bf(x)dx-f(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a)\big|\le\frac{L(b-a)^3}{12}.$$

Comment: I don't see where this $f'(c)(x-c)$ is coming from actually you have: $ \int_a^b f(x)-f(c) dx$ under the integral, why is there a $f'(c)$

Comment: @Lipschitz: It is because $\int_a^b(x-c)dx=0$.

Comment: ah, so you inserted a zero, okay, that was pretty smart ;-)